# insights on intranet with no public internet access

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've seen some cast on //Build 2015 that uses microsoft azure application insights to trace site/application's wealth..I was wondering if there's a way of doing so on a intranet application with restricted internet access.
is there a way of installing insights service on a windows server?
Or does a similar tool exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you won't be able to use ApplicationInsights on a server with restricted internet access because ApplicationInsights needs to send the collected telemetry over to ApplicationInsights service for analysis and aggregation. 
However if you would like to configure a an intermediary endpoint on a server that has internet connection you can replace the endpoint address in ApplicationInsights.config. Inside TelemetryChannel node set the value for EndpointAddress property to your custom endpoint:

```
<TelemetryChannel>
        <EndpointAddress><your custom endpoint></EndpointAddress>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

Then in your intermediary endpoint route the traffic to http://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track

Comment: Thanks for your reply...are you aware of similar tools that saves data on a server? since I've tried to undestand if our cuistomer can allow the log on azure but it doesn't welcome this solution (financial customer)..Thank